# Function produces “Type error” message in application (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I am writing this function that is designed to calculate the number of bits required for the cache index. It uses the formulas and type shown below.

The problem is that it produces the following error message. How can I fix this ?

Source code:

```
getNumBits :: (Integral a, RealFloat a1) => a1 -> [Char] -> [c] -> a
getNumBits fromIntegral(numOfSets) cacheType (x:xs)
  | (cacheType=="fullyAssoc") = 0
  | (cacheType=="setAssoc")   = fromIntegral(logBase2(fromIntegral(length (x:xs)))/numOfSets)
  | (cacheType=="directMap")  = fromIntegral(logBase2(fromIntegral(length (x:xs))))
```

Error message:

```
ERROR file:.\HaskellProject.hs:27 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : fromIntegral (logBase2 (fromIntegral (length (x : xs))) / numOfSets)
*** Term           : logBase2 (fromIntegral (length (x : xs))) / numOfSets
*** Type           : [Char]
*** Does not match : Int
```

Comment: You might consider using, besides just `Integral`, the [Bits class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html) which provides C-like masking operations. Integer and Int types both have instances of the `Bits` class.

Comment: The `fromIntegral` argument to `getNumBits` is strange `getNumBits fromIntegral(numOfSets) cacheType (x:xs)` is the same as `getNumBits fromIntegral numOfSets cacheType (x:xs)` in Haskell, so it will think that `fromIntegral` is one of the arugments to `getNumBits` and it will shadow the usual definition of `fromIntegral`. I don't think you meant to do that.

Comment: What is exactly the intended role of type "c" ? It has no constraints, except that the list may not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
getNumBits fromIntegral(numOfSets) cacheType (x:xs)
```

This isn't haskell, where did you learn this?  You can't apply functions to arguments in this manner.  Instead, bind the argument to a variable and apply the function in the body or a `where` clause:

```
getNumBits numOfSetsFloat cacheType (x:xs)
 ...
 where numOfSets = fromIntegral numOfSetsFloat
```

Also you'll want to handle the empty list case for your last argument or else you'll get a run-time exception when someone calls the function as `getNumBits 0 [] []`.